# Component Rendering with useEffect in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

Consider the following dummy code in React:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Welcome = () => {
  console.log("[Welcome] rendered");

  return <h1>Hello World</h1>;
};

const App = () => {
  console.log("[App] rendered");

  const [myState, setMyState] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("[App - useEffect] Callback");
    setMyState(true);
  });

  return <Welcome />;
};

export default App;
```

The output on console when I run this application is:

```
[App] rendered
[Welcome] rendered
[App - useEffect] Callback
[App] rendered
[Welcome] rendered
[App - useEffect] Callback
[App] rendered
```

**First Doubt:**
Why is the last message which prints `[App] rendered` printed for the third time on console when there is no state change (`myState` is `true` and set to `true` again)? If at all the `App` component is rendered again, why `[Welcome] rendered` is not printed after it?

**Problem Explanation:**
When I run the application, the `App` component renders for the first time giving the message `[App] rendered` on console. Since the `App` component has `Welcome` as its child component, the message `[Welcome] rendered` is printed on console and the child component `Welcome` is mounted on DOM thereby mounting the `App` component too. Once the `App` component is mounted on DOM, the callback function inside the `useEffect` hook gets executed and it prints `[App - useEffect] Callback` on console. The next statement inside this callback function sets the `myState` state variable to `true` (which was previously `false`). Because the state of `App` component has changed, it gets re-rendered. This prints another `[App] rendered` statement on console. To render `App`, `Welcome` component needs to be rendered which prints `[Welcome] rendered` on console. Once the `App` component is rendered (or evaluated) completely, the control goes to the `useEffect` hook and the statement `[useEffect] Callback` is again printed on console. This time again, I set the state variable `myState` to `true` (which was previously also `true`) thereby making no change in state from the previous render and hence there is no re-rendering of the `App` component. Hence, I should not see the third `[App] rendered` message printed on console.

**Second Doubt:**
For my second doubt, consider the slightly changed code given below (set `myState` to `false` in contrast to setting it to `true` earlier):

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Welcome = () => {
  console.log("[Welcome] rendered");

  return <h1>Hello World</h1>;
};

const App = () => {
  console.log("[App] rendered");

  const [myState, setMyState] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("[App - useEffect] Callback");
    setMyState(false);
  });

  return <Welcome />;
};

export default App;
```

The output on console when I run this slightly modified application is:

```
[App] rendered
[Welcome] rendered
[App - useEffect] Callback
```

If the `[App] rendered` was printed for the third time in the previous code, then why is the message `[App] rendered` not getting logged for the second time here? Why there exists an inconsistency between the results of the two code snippets?

**P.S.**
The dummy code is kept trivial so that I can focus more on the concept than the code and I have deliberately not used any dependency array in `useEffect`.

Comment: Remove the unintentional side-effect console logs from the component bodies, the ones in the `useEffect` hooks are when the components rerender ***to the DOM***. See also https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update and https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects may help explain the side-effects.

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you for sharing the links. I think I understand the reasoning behind the output of my first doubt from here - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update. The documentation states - *If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state, React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects and may still need to render that specific component again before bailing out but it won't unnecessarily go “deeper” into the tree.* What I don't understand is why is the behavior not consistent with the second doubt (2nd code ex.)?

Comment: Seems related to the *"...and **may** still need to render that specific component again..."* bit. I suspect that in this case that React has determined the next state is the same as the current and nothing needs to be rerendered.